# how to pass parameters (username and password) to function signinactivity

Tags: java, android, authentication

Here I got another class called `signinactivity` which I wanted to pass username and password to that particular function.

But it seems like something wrong with my code. Anyone got idea with the code?

```
public void loginPost(View view){
    String username = usernameField.getText().toString();
    String password = passwordField.getText().toString();
    new SigninActivity().execute(username, password);
}
```

Comment: And, where is the code?

Comment: Please paste full class code.

Comment: From its name `SigninActivity` we can safely assume that this class is Activity?

Comment: @santosh-patilsorry to everyone of you, I did some mistake with the caption, im actually intended to pass the parameter to a function called doinbackground which inside class signinactivity

Comment: here is the code
public class SigninActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signin);
    }

    override
    protected String doInBackground(){

Comment: ctrl-k seems like doesnt work to standardize the code when replying comment, Im actually just starter with asking question with stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

execute the method with param.

```
new SigninActivity(username, password).execute();
```

You can receive param on the method using a constructor.

```
public SigninActivity(String username,String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
```